# Ошибка при создании нового приложения в App Store Connect

Tags: ios, swift, app, appstore

Пытаюсь создать новое приложение в App Store Connect (ID пакета предварительно создал также), но при сохранении выпадает ошибка "Произошла ошибка. Повторите попытку позже."
До этого много приложений публиковал и никогда такой ошибки не возникало. Скрин приложил. Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобным?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в обновленных соглашениях, которые надо было принять, но не получалось в них зайти с главной страницы.